# Algorithm to categorize arbitrary number of HTML documents into topics

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I've found algorithms that explain how to compare 2 documents to generate a 'closeness' score. Is there a known algorithm that could be used to read a moderate number of HTML documents (double to triple digits) and group them? Ideally without using a 2-input algorithm on every possible permutation of source documents.

I guess Google News must be using something like this.

Just to clarify, here is an example:

```
Input: 100 HTML documents
Output:
- 3 categories found:
* CategoryA:  30 documents
* CategoryB:  20 documents
* CategoryC:  5  documents
* Uncategorised: 45 documents
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific about your grouping criteria.  For example, I could write code that groups articles by number of words, but I doubt that's what you want.  Regarding your Google News example, I imagine articles aren't grouped into single categories.  More likely, multiple tags can be assigned to an article depending upon its content, and then these tags can be used to mix and match articles into many different groupings, depending on the search criteria.

Comment: I would like the articles/documents grouped by their topics. I know 'topic' is vague, but that's part of the difficulty in coming up with the algorithm. As a human it seems simple to do, but hard to explain. For a computer I guess it would be a combination of the words, their order and placement. I can also see how someone could spend an eternity getting this right, but any simple algorithms to get started with would be helpful. Thx

Comment: Maybe you could use [Topic models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) specifically [Latent Dirichlet allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation). Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into algorithms in the area of [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). You seem to be looking for a very broad method of [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) but you can improve the quality of the results if you add some additional input to the algorithm before searching for categories.

You will need to come up with a way of comparing the documents or at least enumerating the relevant characteristics (length, frequency of words, et cetera). These can serve as input to the clustering algorithm that you're using. For example, you could define the following characteristics:

- number of words
- number of images
- number of external links
- number of words related to geography
- number of words related to biology
- number of words related to economy
- et cetera

The more specific you are about what categories you want, the better the algorithms perform. The above characteristics will give you a vector of number for each document:

```
(384 , 12,  8, ...,  0)
(1244, 39, 10, ..., 55)
(128 ,  2, 66, ..., 33)
...
```

A clustering algorithm (such as [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)) can now help you in assigning each document to the most likely cluster. Note that this is just an example. For your particular problem it may be useful to define more specific characteristics for a more specific domain (such as medical articles).

Comment: Didn't use k-means, but 'clustering' led be on the right path. accepting.